# Assigning values to a User class variable

Tags: laravel

During my login process, I try to add a variable to my User class model, which I do not want to store in the database. So I extended my User.php like this:

```
private $roles;
protected $appends = ['roles'];

public function getRolesAttribute()
{
    //dd($this->roles);
    return $this->roles;
}

public function setRolesAttribute($value)
{
    $this->roles = ($value);
}
```

Im my login class I try to assign some information like this:
$user->roles = $ldap_roles;

But unfortunately the data is not saved and when I call the Auther::User() in my blade the role value is null, or maybe better said never set. I guess the problem is that the user is never really saved, but as I said before, I don’t want to store the ldap_roles information in the database.

Any tips?

Thanks
Stephan

---

Hi,
So I updated my table with a new column roles and store the LDAP groups there. After each login I assign the roles and do a update. I am not really happy with this solution but I couldn’t find another way.

```
        $user->roles = json_encode($ldap_roles);
        $user->update();
```

Comment: Hmmm... can you give us a bit more details on why you do not want to save the data, that may be useful to give you an answers. Is it between calls? the only thing I can come up with this information would be to have some type of user singleton where you can set a property and make sure when you try to get the user again is the one instance to which you have added the role.

Comment: Hey,
The reason why I don’t want to store this information is because I am using a LDAP authentication and it is required during the login process to check in which groups the user is a member of. This can of course change and I don’t want to maintain this in the database. Therefore, during the login process I am grapping the LDAP groups and want to use them later for the role permissions. I hope this explains it a bit better.

$group = Adldap::search()->groups()->findorfail($ldap_group);

Comment: If you want to save the data across requests, while not storing it in database, you have to store it in [session](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/session).

Comment: Thanks. This also works. The only thing is, I have to use Session::put and get not just use ” session(['ldap_roles' => json_encode($ldap_roles)]);
”. This implicates that I also have to add “use Session;” to every class I am using it.